# How to prevent unnecessary encoding in Wikidata query from Neo4j?

Tags: encoding, neo4j, sparql

I am trying to run through the tutorial here: https://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2020/02/04/neo4j-enriching-existing-graph-wikidata-sparql-api/

However, when I get to the Cypher query that produces the Table 3 results:

```
MATCH (player:Player)
WHERE player.name = "Nick Kyrgios"
WITH "SELECT *
WHERE { ?person wdt:P106 wd:Q10833314 ;
                rdfs:label \"" + player.name + "\"@en ;
                wdt:P569 ?dateOfBirth ;
                wdt:P27 [ rdfs:label ?countryName ] .
       filter(lang(?countryName) = \"en\")
}" AS sparql
CALL apoc.load.jsonParams(
  "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=" + apoc.text.urlencode(sparql),
  { Accept: "application/sparql-results+json"},
  null
)
YIELD value
RETURN value
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.jsonParams`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read url or key https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=SELECT+*%250AWHERE+%257B+%253Fperson+wdt%253AP106+wd%253AQ10833314+%253B%250A++++++++++++++++rdfs%253Alabel+%2522Nick+Kyrgios%2522%2540en+%253B%250A++++++++++++++++wdt%253AP569+%253FdateOfBirth+%253B%250A++++++++++++++++wdt%253AP27+%255B+rdfs%253Alabel+%253FcountryName+%255D+.%250A+++++++filter%2528lang%2528%253FcountryName%2529+%253D+%2522en%2522%2529%250A%257D as json: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=SELECT+*%250AWHERE+%257B+%253Fperson+wdt%253AP106+wd%253AQ10833314+%253B%250A++++++++++++++++rdfs%253Alabel+%2522Nick+Kyrgios%2522%2540en+%253B%250A++++++++++++++++wdt%253AP569+%253FdateOfBirth+%253B%250A++++++++++++++++wdt%253AP27+%255B+rdfs%253Alabel+%253FcountryName+%255D+.%250A+++++++filter%2528lang%2528%253FcountryName%2529+%253D+%2522en%2522%2529%250A%257D

When I run the Sparql query by itself on Wikidata's sandbox, I get no errors. I think the issue is related to  encoding (the URL in the error message has additional "25"s, presumably because it is double-encoding all of the % signs). When I copy/paste the URL from the error message and manually remove all of the 25's, it connects to Wikidata and returns a JSON file just fine.

I have tried Cypher's REPLACE() function to eliminate the extra 25's but it doesn't get rid of them and I end up with the same error message.

Has anyone encountered this problem and found a way to fix it?

Ubuntu 20.04, Neo4j Desktop 1.4.5, I installed the APOC plugin

Answer (score 1):

Mark's otherwise excellent post is out-of-date now, so there are two issues preventing your query from running:

1. Newer versions of APOC handle the encoding, so you don't want to include the `apoc.text.urlencode()` function.
2. New line characters in the SPARQL string cause problems and we need to get rid of them.

Try this code:

```
WITH 'SELECT * WHERE { ?person wdt:P106 wd:Q10833314 ; rdfs:label "Nick Kyrgios"@en ; wdt:P569 ?dateOfBirth ; wdt:P27 [ rdfs:label ?countryName ] . filter(lang(?countryName) = "en")}' AS sparql
CALL apoc.load.jsonParams("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=" + sparql,
  { Accept: "application/sparql-results+json"},
  null
)
YIELD value
RETURN value
```

Note that I used `'` to surround the URL string, but you can use `"` if you'd rather. Just remember to use `\"` to escape any double quotes within the string, as Mark shows in his post. E.g., ...`rdfs:label \"Nick Kyrgios\"@en`...

My environment:
Via web browser on neo4j Enterprise 4.3.5
APOC version 4.3.0.3